# iOS: Add Button over NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, uibutton, nsattributedstring

I want to know if is possible to put a UIButton over a exactly coordinate of a piece of text.

For example, my UILabel have this text:

**"Dont have an account? *Sign In*"**

In the italic content, I need to put a button over then, the touch over this button will trigger an action that will open a Sign In View

Is very important to make this feature well, to work with same in other languages without do anything :)

Thanks

Comment: hey you got the answer?

Comment: @サンディープ I answered the question, check out please. I hope this can be helpful for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll respond my answer because this can be helpful for other developers that got the same problem.

**1**: You need to implement UITextViewDelegate method:
`- (BOOL)textView:shouldInteractWithURL:inRange:`

The implementation is very simple, basically, you will compare the received link in NSURL. I like to compare by host using the NSURL components when I have many links, for example:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange
{
  NSString *urlScheme     = URL.scheme;
  NSString *host          = URL.host;

  if([urlScheme isEqualToString:@"myapp"])
  {
    if([host isEqualToString:@"/signin"])
      [self.onSignRequest( self )];
  }

  return YES;
}
```

This method will be called when user touch over link.

**2**: Create two `NSString` instances, one for the string `"Don't have an account?"` and another one for string `"Sign Up"`

```
NSString *labelText = @"Don't have an account? ";
NSString *linkedText = @"Sign Up";
```

**3**: Create a `NSMutableAttributedString` instance with both strings concated:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithAttributedString:[AttributedText attributedStringWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", labelText, linkedText]
                                                                                                                                          font:[UIFOnt systemFontOfSize:14.f]
                                                                                                                                         color:[UIColor blueColor]]];
```

**4**: Create a range for a linked text from the mutable attributed string created before:

```
NSRange range = [[attributedString  string] rangeOfString:linkedText];
```

**5**: Create an string to

**5**: Add a new `NSLinkAttributeName` for the mutable string with the range created in step **4**

```
[attributedString addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:URLStringLink range:range];
```

**6**: Add the mutable string to UILabel using `attributedText` property of `UILabel`

```
_label.attributedText = attributedText;
```

**7**: Set the delegate of label:

```
_label.delegate = textViewDelegate;
```

And that's it. I hope this can be helpful for anyone needs to add "touchable" links in `UILabel`

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to make them into two different labels and set the button frame to the second label's frame.  The harder way would be to go through creating string sizes and manually create the CGRect for the button.  That method would be something like this:

```
CGSize dontSize = [@"Dont have an account?" sizeWithFont:label.font];
CGSize signinSize = [@"Sign In" sizeWithFont:label.font];

//Originate to the whole label's frame
CGRect buttonFrame = label.frame;
buttonFrame.origin.x += dontSize.width;
buttonFrame.size.width = signinSize.width;
```

Comment: I think if I use two (or more when need) UILabels, it's will be very problematic to update when change the app locale. I'm thinking in a more smart approach to works with any language.

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented something similar. You can simply add a Tap Gesture Recognizer to the View Controller in Interface Builder and link it with the label.

The Tap Gesture Recognizer has an IBAction method you can put your code in. The area of the tap gesture recognizer will automatically match the label.

You can also use Attributed Text on the label to make it appear like a link (with color and underline).

Comment: Tab Gesture is a really good in the case of you need to get tap on the label. In my case, I need to add action only in a specified part of the UILabel's text. I think I need a method to get a CGRect from a specified text, and with this CGRect I can put that against the CGPoint from locationInView method from UIGestureRecognizer. This is my idea but I don't know if is possible to take the CGRect from a text range.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to trigger an action from your italic text you should add an `NSLinkAttributeName`additionally to your `NSFontAttributeName`. Choose whatever you want as link, like `myapp://action1`.

Then use a `UITextView` instead of a `UILabel` and assign your class as delegate and implement

`- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL *)URL
         inRange:(NSRange)characterRange`

Do whatever action you want to do in there and return NO, which will prevent Safari do get started.

Answer (score -2):

### Covering part of UILabel

- Separate into 2 UILabels and then set the frame to match Sign In Label:

> ```
> [button setFrame:signinLabel.frame];
> [button setCenter:signinLabel.center];
> ```

**OR**

- Guess the coordinates until you set the *(hard-coded)* frame properly of UIButton

**OR**

- Remove "Sign In" from UILabel and make it be the title of
  UIButton