# Unexpected SafariViewController reaction

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sfsafariviewcontroller

I have an app with some Table View Controllers. In the last one of each cell I have a different url. I decided then to insert a SafariVC, but what is occurring is that it is like it was as a FirstResponder.

```
class Page3: UITableViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {

    ...

    @IBOutlet weak var websiteTextView: UITextView!

    ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ...

        websiteTextView.text = goP3.website

        let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: URL(string: goP3.website)!)
        present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
        safariVC.delegate = self

        ...
    }
}
```

[image: gif]

After watch the gif above, I have two doubts:

**1st.** When I go into the `Page3`,  it auto-opens the SafariViewController. How do I fix it?

**2st.** When I click on the url, it doesn't open the SafariViewController. What do I have to do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1) 1st Question answer is below:
You need to remove below code from ViewDidLoad Method:

```
websiteTextView.text = goP3.website
let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: URL(string: goP3.website)!)
present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
safariVC.delegate = self
```

For 2) 2nd Question answer is below:
You need to create a UIButton and set title text for goP3.website. Then Create IBAction method for that UIButton. something like below

```
@IBOutlet weak var btnWebsite: UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ...
    btnOK.setTitle(goP3.website, for: .normal)
}
@IBAction func btnWebsiteSelect(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: URL(string: goP3.website)!)
    present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    safariVC.delegate = self
}
```

Comment: I think I need 'websiteTextView.text = goP3.website' because it makes the text be show in the textView. And I don't think a button is gonna work. Because sometimes I have 3 or 4 URLs inside the same textView. Sorry, I forgot to explain this bafore. Do you have another suggestion?

Comment: Yes, there are different ways to do. But the default behavior of UITextView is : Link will be open in Safari App only.

I think you need to follow this link. If you find not helpful then let me know. I will help you with other solution. Just add a new comment here that it is helpful or not.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278169/ios-add-button-over-nsattributedstring

Comment: I read and check step by step. But unfortunately sometimes I have more than one URL inside the same textView. So putting a transparent button on top of the links would cause confusion between the links. Would not it be possible to change the default/pattern of opening links in textView?